# c function of my shared lib is not seen out of the lib

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have developed this so lib:
mylib.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int foo(int a,int b) {
return 1;
}
```

mylib.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int foo(int a,int b);
```

Makefile (libmylib.so is generated successfully in lib folder):

```
CFLAGS += -g -Wall -Werror -Wpointer-arith -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing
OBJECTS = mylib.o
MY_LIBRARY := libmylib.so

all: $(MY_LIBRARY)

$(MY_LIBRARY): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -fPIC -rdynamic -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o ./lib/$@  $^

$(OBJECTS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ${@:.o=.c} -o $@
    
clean :
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f ./lib/$(MY_LIBRARY)
```

my test program:
test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mylib.h> //mylib.h was copied to /usr/include

int main () {
foo(5,2);
return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -c test.c -o test.o => pass
gcc -L./lib -lmylib test.o -o TEST => fail
```

ERROR:

```
user~/Desktop/test_lib$ gcc -L./lib -lmylib test.o -o TEST
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand why it fails when generating my program ?

Comment: Please show [mcve].

Comment: `gcc -L./lib -lmylib -o TEST` seems to be missing an argument.

Comment: You can see my update (the missing argument is added, there is not the error)

Comment: it seems my mylib is not usable, but I don't understand why

Comment: @EugeneSh. the program that I have added in my question is ready to reproduce my issue

Comment: You have posted two different errors - what are these? Which one is the actual one?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the second I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this error with just change the order of options in gcc command when linking to mylib, I haven't an explanation but this fixed my issue.

```
user:~/Desktop/test_lib$ gcc -L./lib -lmylib test.o -o TEST
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
user:~/Desktop/test_lib$ gcc -L./lib test.o -o TEST -lmylib
user:~/Desktop/test_lib$ ls -l
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 nov.  16 19:15 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  346 nov.  16 19:00 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   54 nov.  16 18:20 mylib.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   22 nov.  16 18:20 mylib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 2632 nov.  16 19:15 mylib.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user group 8592 nov.  17 14:20 TEST
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   56 nov.  16 18:21 test.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 v 1376 nov.  16 19:15 test.o
user:~/Desktop/test_lib$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use **-I** option on the **gcc** command line, you don't need to pollute */usr/include* with test files:

```
gcc -c test.c -o test.o -I.
```

The order of the files on the linking command line is important. Put libraries after the file which use them:

```
$ gcc -L./lib -lmylib test.o -o TEST
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc test.o -L./lib -lmylib  -o TEST
$
```

Then, use **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable to add the pathname of your library in the list of search paths of the dynamic linker (it is advised to use an absolute pathname but for test purposes, I use a relative one):

```
$ ./TEST
./TEST: error while loading shared libraries: libmylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ ldd TEST
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeb8bf1000)
    libmylib.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f268fe40000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2690056000)
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./lib
$ ldd TEST
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd75bcb000)
    libmylib.so => ./lib/libmylib.so (0x00007f16ff112000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f16fef03000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f16ff11e000)
$ ./TEST
$
```